# datepicker not sending value with rest of form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-datepicker, simple-form

I used to use the 'ui_datepicker-rails3' gem to deal with my date pickers but have subsequently retired it with the view to moving things to rails 4 eventually. In addition to figuring out that 'jquery-ui-rails', '>=5.0' deals with date pickers quite nicely.

```
  = simple_form_for job, :url => job_path(job), :html => { :method => :put } do |f|
    = f.input :booked_date, :label => "Reschedule for", :as => :datepicker
    = f.input :job_card_id, :label => "or add to", :hint => "Job Card for today", :as => :select, :collection => @job_cards, label_method: :franchisee_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: true
    = f.input :last_message, :label => "Reason for reschedule"
.actions  
      = f.submit "Reschedule", :class => "btn btn-primary"
      = link_to "Do not reschedule", job_path(job), :class => "btn btn-secondary"
```

This is a simple form and the layout, date picker and everything works exactly as it did before.

With one exception

The dates that are picked are not making it in to the submitted forms' values

```
Processing by JobsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x+8Lw1NMmYIIySUcp9JeTDXzGnHYqL6hCWkof6nK/0Y=", "job"=>{"booked_date"=>"", "job_card_id"=>"", "last_message"=>"jh"}, "commit"=>"Reschedule", "id"=>"1001787"}
```

If I change the field type to :as => text and type the date in, it's fine. It I comment out the field type (so it defaults to the 3 select date combo) it also works.

coffee script for completion

```
$ ->
  $("#job_booked_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
    minDate: 0
      });
```

What gives? The values seem to be in there when I date pick them, but it's not being sent in the form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, thanks to a lot of not-quite-the-solution until [this post](http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=557).

In my conversion from using :date_picker to :datepicker as a simple_form field type, I had to create an input wrapper in config/initializers/datepicker.rb

```
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options) + \
    @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, { :class => attribute_name.to_s + "-alt"})
  end
end
```

Upon removing the '-alt' section, functionality has been returned to normal

```
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  end
end
```

I had more than one #job_booked_date (and, for that matter, every other date picker ID was being duplicated)